# What entitlements/permissions does the device pin controller class require?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, jailbreak

My iphone app is jailbroken and I don't care if my app is rejected by the app store.

I wish to use the private API `DevicePINController` in my program.

I recently found the private API called `DevicePINController`, however it doesn't work properly.  The app runs and all but its methods do nothing.  Its `BOOL` methods always return false.  Set methods don't do anything.

Does anyone know what entitlements permissions the device pin controller requires?

**EDIT:CODE**

```
    id away = [[objc_getClass("DevicePINController") alloc]init];

    NSLog( [away simplePIN] ? @"YES":@"NO" );
    NSLog( [away _isBlocked] ? @"YES":@"NO" );
    NSLog( [away _attemptValidationWithPIN:@"1234"] ? @"YES":@"NO" );

    NSLog(@"%d",[away _unblockTime] );
    NSLog(@"%@",[away blockedStateKey] );
    NSLog(@"%@",[away blockTimeIntervalKey] );
    NSLog(@"%@",[away failedAttemptsKey] );
    NSLog(@"%d",[away pinLength] );
    NSLog(@"%@",[away stringsBundle] );

    NSLog(@"%@",[away stringsTable]);
```

Every method call returns the wrong answer.  Some only return null.  Bool always return NO.

Comment: You'd need to show us the code you're running for us to be able to help you debug why it's not working.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested whether `away` is equal to `nil`?  Remember in Objective-C, sending a *message* to a nil object will just do nothing.  If the method is supposed to return a `BOOL`, the default value of `BOOL` is `NO`, so you'll get back a bunch of NOs if `away` is nil.

Comment: It seems you're right.away is nil.But is'nt this the right way to use a private api?

Comment: How are you opening `Preferences.framework`?  Is it included in your project settings (Build Phases)?  Or, is it opened dynamically, with `dlopen()`?  Let me know if you're unsure about the meaning of these two options.

Comment: I did not understand your meaning.Should I use link binary with libraries to find and link preferences.framework? It is not currently added to my project.I thought we did'nt need to add any frameworks when using objc_getClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first problem is that you have a `nil` object.  In Objective-C, sending a message to a `nil` object will just do nothing. If the method is supposed to return a `BOOL`, the default value of `BOOL` is `NO`, so you'll get back a bunch of NOs if away is nil.

To answer your follow-up question (after you tested that you did actually have a `nil` value) ... you **do** need to make sure your app opens the library where the `DevicePINController` is defined.  Otherwise, it won't know what that class is, and won't be able to instantiate it.  So, `objc_getClass` will return you the `nil` object.

For that class, it is defined in **Preferences.framework**, found at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework
```

(obviously, adjust for your installation directory and/or SDK version)

You can either add it to your project in Xcode, by going to the target settings -> **Build Phases** -> **Link Binary With Libraries** and adding it.  You'll of course have to navigate to the directory above, since it's a Private Framework, and won't show up in the initial popup list.

Or, you can use code to dynamically load the library:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
```

and

```
void* libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Preferences", RTLD_LAZY);

id away = [[objc_getClass("DevicePINController") alloc] init];
if (away == nil) {
    NSLog(@"object is nil");
} else {
    if ([away respondsToSelector: @selector(simplePIN)]) {
        NSLog(@"object responds to selector!");
    }
}

close(libHandle);
```

I tested this on iOS 6.1 (jailbroken) and it works.

By the way, please change your PIN to something other than `1234`.  I have the same combination on my luggage ;)

Comment: What is RTLD_LAZY ? Its giving an error."Use of undeclared identifier RTLD_LAZY"

Comment: sorry, there's one more `#include <dlfcn.h>` that you need for that constant.  see my updated code above.

Comment: The attempt validation with pin still returns the wrong answer.It should return YES but it returns no.even though my pin is 1234

Comment: Yeah, `_attemptValidationWithPIN` doesn't work for me either.  At this point, there's a million things that could be going wrong.  Maybe an *entitlement* is needed?  Maybe the parameter is not supposed to be a `NSString`?  Maybe the string is hashed or salted, to prevent reverse engineering?  Maybe there's another call that needs to be made first, to setup the controller?  This is where iOS hacking gets difficult, and time-consuming.  Have you found any information on this class elsewhere?

Comment: No There is no info available.I just need to set a pin to the iphone.It doesnt matter if attemptvalidationwithpin does'nt work :)

Comment: Yeah, there's a whole bunch of other things that might be necessary.  There could be a soft reboot of SpringBoard that's needed for the changes to take effect.  You might have to set the old password (`setOldPassword:`) before it'll let you change the PIN.  There might be a notification you have to post to update settings, once you've called `setPIN`.  The possibilities are almost endless :(

Comment: @iOsBoy, incidentally, I'm pretty sure this requires your app to have the `com.apple.managedconfiguration.profiled-access` entitlement, but I tried it, and it still didn't work for me.  So, I think *more* is still missing.